# Make background render and actively participate to simulation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I tracked a 17 second video where I had a bunch of dots on a macbook. I want to make it look like there is shattered glass in front of the mac. Currently working on concepts, I ran into a problem: The background video does not render in the final render (It does in the viewport render) (I'm using Cycles)

This is what it looks like in viewport render:
[image]
All of the pillars are made of glass, with an IOR of 1.1 and 0 Roughness.

Some people online say to enable/disable transparent under film.

With transparent on (F12 Render)
[image]

Without transparent on (F12 Render)
[image]

Here's my Background settings:
[image]

Then my render settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to add the background image as a plane and use it as part of the 3D scene to be properly integrated.

Comment: @cegaton any tips on doing this easily? Properly scaling it to the camera doesn't sound like fun

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464 that will make your background image render behind the 3d scene... but to make the glass interact with the screen, the screen itself  has to be an object in the 3d environment.

Comment: @cegaton Please repeat that in answer form so I can credit you the rep