# The Background image is not showing in the rendered slot

Tags: image

I checked "transparent" under the Film tab but still not showing.
I can find out what I did wrong.

the file:
[image]
Can someone help? :)

(Edit: my question was if it is possible to render the Background image without compositing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to composite in a background picture?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture)

Comment: The background image on the viewport is used as reference only. Use the compositor to combine the 3d scene over your image. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464

Comment: Did I understand correctly? that it's not possible to render it? that it has to be composed in post prod? 
I had thought in this question that it was possible:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode
but it may be a blender version thing? I have 2.77, on that post the person has 2.74, mmh, I dont know...?

Answer (score 3):

Without using additional geometry or compositing, you can use the image as background for the world. Set the Texture coordinates to Window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Cegaton's answer is much simpler, but it won't work if You're trying to render glass or glossy materials, because the reflection/refractions won't show. If you're using either of those, You'll need to do this ↓

It is not possible to render the viewport background, [I've tried, and failed.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64506/make-background-render-and-actively-participate-to-simulation)

What I ended up doing is just adding in the background in post-processing, like using After Effects (Though this is possible with Blender)

If your scene uses refraction like glass or glossy layers, it might be a good idea to create a plane as the background.

So, for example purposes, I composed a scene with shards of glass, a camera, and a light.
[image]

The first thing you should do is *create a plane.* Then rotate the plane so that it is parallel with the camera, then move it backwards so it is behind everything else.
[image]

Then, go into the Camera by pressing `0` and go into edit mode by pressing `Tab`.

Then, you'll move each of the edge vertices of the plane as accurately into the corners of the camera scene as possible.
[image]

So you should end up with something like this:
[image]

Then go to the *Materials* tab for the plane, and add (`+`) a material. Change it from `Diffuse BSDF` to `Emission`. Then Press the Circle next to `Color` and change it to `Image Texture` You should get something similar to this:
[image]
If the texture appears out of scale, try changing *Flat* to *Box*.
You'll notice there is gray in the refraction of the glass. This is because it is picking up light (Or should I say, a lack of light) from the rest of the scene outside of the textured file. To fix this...

Create a **sphere** and **scale it up** so that it overlaps the entire scene. Then, add the Emission texture to it the same as with the plane. You'll notice the texture doesn't show up properly, probably is just a solid color. This is because you haven't UV unwrapped it.

To unwrap it, go into *edit mode* with `Tab` Select a ring that goes through the center of the sphere.
[image]

Then hit `CTRL+E` and choose *mark seam*. Then hit `U` and choose *Unwrap*.

Then switch the panel to the *UV image editor*

[image]

It should look like two ovals.
[image]

Now you'll want to scale these up and down with `s`. If you open 3D View and do `Shift+Z` to do a makeshift realtime render, you can see as you scale up and down that the texture formatting on the sphere changes. Scale it so that a single texture on the sphere is around the size of the plane, then you can close the UV editor, like this:

[Click here for image, it was too big to upload](https://i.gyazo.com/464064cba8a1a9780c40ec040652d518.gif)

Then if we go back to the camera and render, you will see that there are no more gray spots.
[image]

If there are any problems, I'm willing to help. Sorry if this answer seems unorganized. I'm still new to Stack-Exchange and am currently trying to find an answer format I like.