# Background images not rendering

Tags: rendering

Trying to place a background image into the scene that renders with the scene. The camera view shows the image nut it's not there when rendered. Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles not rendering image or movie clip used as background in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/brand-new-to-blender-background-image-wont-render-with-model

Answer (score 0):

Background and reference images are not intended to be rendered.

To render an image, you should place it on a surface (plane for instance).

A quick way to do it is to use an addon called 'image as plane' which is in the standard distribution.

Activate it:

[image]

Use it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That answers the question!