# The render view does not show background image after i set up the tracking scene. What settings should i make?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Ive made a 3d tracking scene using a planar tracker. After tracking and setting up the scene, while rendering the background image does not shows up in the rendered output. How can i render the background image that i imported as image sequence with the 3d tracked object?

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79). Is this the render engine you are using?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65212/the-background-image-is-not-showing-in-the-rendered-slot