# Cycles. Why is the background on my layer not transparent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

I am new to blender and cannot get the compositor to work. I have a model plane and a background video:
[image]
In videos I have seen it work but it doesnt work for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to enable the transparency. What render engine are you using?

Comment: Do you mean from the drop down menu at the top? I am using Cycles Render

Comment: Enable film transparency

Comment: Where can I find this?

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464

Comment: I am trying to get the plane model to show in front of the video and it still doesnt work and im confused

Comment: Once you enable transparency on the plane layer you should be able to composite it over the background using the nodes you've set up. Make sure you connect the composite node to the output of the alpha over node

Comment: Oh sorry I was being blind as usual and hadn't put the plane in the frame. Thanks for the help, your solution fixed it.