# Background Video is shown in Rendered mode but not when szene is rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

i have a 3D Object and want to add a background image( if possible even a movie) to this 3D Object. I use Cycles to render and tried a plane with the 
image as texture. When i go into render mode, it looks like this(picture with background) and when rendered, it has no background. The key also looks into 
a different direction.

Should i even use Cycles for this or use motion tracking? i tried to use that but had several problems.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/huDsX.jpg

Rendered mode
[image]

When scene is rendered

[image]

Comment: Duplicate as said above. The only thing I would add is that if you want to have a video instead of a static image, you need to use motion tracking without a doubt.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try any of these node setups in the compositor:

**Movie as background:**

[image]

**Image as background:**

[image]

Source:
[cycles not rendering movie clip used as background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464)

Comment: If you are going to blatantly copy and paste an answer... at least show the link to the original one...

Comment: Of course, sorry!