# Camera tracking background is not visible

Tags: rendering, tracking

[image]

[image]

transparent was checked in render tab but I unchecked now what to do. I am trying to render video within mesh a uv sphere so I can see only sphere not video in render time what to do.

Comment: Prashant, can you please elaborate and describe your issue in more details. You can use the Edit button to revise it. Thanks.

Comment: Please help video is not render at render time

Comment: Your question is too vague. You have to explain better what the issue is. Please edit your question to clarify, that will increase the chance of getting an answer. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your render layers are not generating an alpha channel. Did you enable Film->Transparent? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of the nodes you are using in the compositor.

Comment: Related: [Cycles not rendering image or movie clip used as background in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464)