# Background Video Rendering

Tags: rendering

I am about to render an Animation with a background video and already did it once, but I'm too stupid to remember how I did it, and can't find any useful tutorial how to do it. So I set the Video as Background "Image", turned on Paper Sky in the "World"-Section and created a Texture with the Video, so what did I forget? When I render it, there's only an image of it in the background but it's not moving.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a better method to use compositor instead and load your image sequence there, then pass your render layer with transparent BG and mix them with an Alpha Over. You will have much more control over your final output and this method is proven for both BI and Cycles.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464