# Camera tracking; movie clip does not show up as background footage

Tags: camera, tracking

I tried to replicate what Andrew Price did by creating a large sink hole in the middle of the road using blender.

https://youtu.be/CVPcT0dJmoY

I have tried to replicate it, but I am stuck somewhere. 
I am trying to import an OBJ object which I  modeled in blender, into a movie clip.
 I have done the necessary things required to track the movie clip.

I started by inserted my tracking marks on to high contrast area in the movie clip, then have tracked it and it tracked successfully.

So when I click the solve button to generate the tracking data,  it does that successfully.

I then proceeded to add an object Constraints, by clicking on the "Object constraints panel" button, then selected a camera solver. 
Then I could see the tracking markers displayed in the 3D view. When I hit alt 'A',  I can see the camera moving according to the tracking data generated for my footage.

I then split the view.  Then I proceeded to create another view port. 
I left the left view port to be on '3D view', then I selected the right view port to be on 'movie clip editor'. 
However, when I try to Click the  "set as  background" button,  the movie footage does not show up on the left view port. I have tried all I could, but the movie does not show up as a background movie clip for the left view port.

Please is there any button or box that I need to select or tick, that I am missing to click here?

Comment: Thanks.. I could see the movie as background when I press the numpad zero

Answer (score 1):

After tracking and solving press Setup tracking scene, and then "set as backgroud".

That will set the movieclip to be used as image background for camera view.

If you want to set it manually , then just enable images as background, select your video clip as source and go to camera view on the vieport (<kbd>numpad zero</kbd>)

Also, before you ask, the background image is used for reference only, to render the image in the backcground read> [Cycles not rendering image or movie clip used as background in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464)