# Motion tracking, background video not showing behind my scene

Tags: compositing-nodes

When i render the video is not playing in the background, it is just black.

Edit; it's not black it's whatever I set the background color to.

[image]

Comment: Nvm i fixed it i just had to check transparant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles not rendering image or movie clip used as background in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport)